# Can't write at GPIO pins

Tags: rpi.gpio

I turn on my raspberry pi 2 B, and I use the terminal using this command

```
gpio readall
```

And I get this results:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5V      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 1 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

As you can see 21 and 22 are stuck at HIGH. How can I resolve that?

I'm using a extension board that connects `raspberry` to `protoboard`. I'm using `Pi Cobbler Plus Kit Breakout Raspberry Pi B+`  to do this.

I did a simple circuit using a external protoboard, I try to explain clearly.

I connect `21 pin` to a `protoboard` column and in the same column I connect largest `led` side.

In other `protoboard column` I connect `GND` from `GPIO` and connect to the other `led` side. And between `GND` and `Led` I used a little resistor.

The final step I change `21 pin` to `output` and write `1` on it. And the led doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 21 and 22?

Comment: You may have destroyed the LED.  You make no mention of a current limiting resistor to prevent damage to the LED.

Comment: This question needs to be closed as it has been abandoned for two months without the required and explicitly requested clarification ever being provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean GPIO.21 & GPIO.22 (21 & 22 is ambiguous - there are 3 pins designated 21).
There are inputs, so the value would depend on what (if anything) is connected to them.

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: light on a led light.

Comment: If you want help you need to tell us what you have tried. Obviously you can't output if the pins are configured as inputs. There are several different ways of doing this. You should try searching to find others similar.

Comment: I followed this simple tutorial (`https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/tux-crossing/gpio-examples-1-a-single-led/`) to light on a led, but I can't do that

Comment: The link does not work, but obviously you did not follow. I ran most of Gordon's examples years ago. If you want help tell us WHAT YOU HAVE ACTUALLY DONE, not a link which you may have followed correctly or not. NOTE post any detail into your question, not as a comment.